# Rendering Ligatures in PDFs in Chrome on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, pdf, osx-lion

When viewing pdf files in Google Chrome on OSX Lion, certain PDFs do not render properly. Namely, when there are ligatures (an `fi` combination or a `ff` combination) the two letters are replaced with a small white box, as if the font could not be found. When I download the same PDF and view it in Preview, it renders just fine.

Is there a way to fix this rendering issue? Do I have to install some font or something?

Comment: Could you provide an example PDF?

Comment: @Daniel Beck -- http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/segment.pdf

Comment: It seems to be this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59338

Comment: I don't even get a box, Just blank spaces where they should go. (and this is on the Windows version of Chrome.)